# Getting points from an anonymous function after integration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to get value of `v(U,n0)` for various points in MATLAB

```
eq = @(q,U,n0) 2*(1-cos(2*pi*q));
hq = @(q,U,n0) ((eq)^2+2*U*n0*(eq))^(1/2);
y = @(q,U,n0) (((eq)+(U*n0))/hq)-1;
a = -0.5;
b = 0.5;
v = @(U,n0) quad(@(q) y(q,U,n0),a,b);
```

But I get lots of errors like

```
>> v(1,2)
  Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Error in @(q,U,n0)(((eq)+(U*n0))/hq)-1

Error in @(q)y(q,U,n0)

Error in quad (line 72) y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in @(U,n0)quad(@(q)y(q,U,n0),a,b)
```

Can anybody help me out with the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using function handles without specifying their arguments. For example, after you define `eq(q,U,n0)`, you use it in `hq` like a variable (`eq`) without  any inputs. Whenever you use a function, you must give it inputs, so use `eq(q,U,n0)`, not just `eq`.

Comment: I have changed my code, but I am still facing the following errors:

_italic_ **bold** 'U = 1;    
eq = @(q) 2*(1-cos(2*pi*q));
hq = @(q,n0) ((eq(q))^2+2*U*n0*(eq(q))).^0.5;
y = @(q,n0) (((eq(q))+(U*n0))/hq(q,n0))-1;
a = -0.5;
b = 0.5;
v = @(n0) quad(@(q) y(q,n0),a,b);
cv =@(n0) n0+(0.5*v(n0))-1;
while U < 20
n0 = 0.1;
options = optimset('Display', 'iter'); 
n = fsolve(cv(n0),n0,0.1,options);
plot(U,n)
hold on 
U = U + 1;
 end'

Comment: _errors: 
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.

Error in @(q,n0)((eq(q))^2+2*U*n0*(eq(q))).^0.5


Error in @(q,n0)(((eq(q))+(U*n0))/hq(q,n0))-1


Error in @(q)y(q,n0)


Error in quad (line 72)
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in @(n0)quad(@(q)y(q,n0),a,b)


Error in @(n0)n0+(0.5*v(n0))-1


Error in simulv1 (line 12)
n = fsolve(cv(n0),n0,0.1,options);_

Comment: It would be easier to edit your question with this, but basically you are doing matrix exponentiation, not element-wise exponentiation. Replace `*` by `.*`, and `/` by `./` and t ought to work. But it's hard to tell just looking at your comments. If that doesn't fix it, edit your question to include those details.